# Docker build fails COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

My docker build fails randomly from Azure Devops , once build fails and the next is successful , this is so annoying can some one please help??

My docker command :  `docker build -t ${{ parameters.servicename }}:$a .`

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20181114
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless 
ARG JAR_FILE='**/*.jar'
ADD ${JAR_FILE} content_mgmt_service.jar
ADD entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]      # split ENTRYPOINT wrapper from
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/content_mgmt_service.jar"] # main CMD
```

error :

```
When using ADD with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /
```

I tried this :

```sh
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20181114
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless 
ARG JAR_FILE='**/*.jar'
ADD ${JAR_FILE} content_mgmt_service.jar
ADD entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]      # split ENTRYPOINT wrapper from
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/content_mgmt_service.jar"] # main CMD
```

I tried `ADD entrypoint.sh ./` (with `/` at the end) but it still fails.  What might be going wrong?

Comment: What do you expect Docker to do if `ADD **/*.jar content_mgmt_service.jar` finds multiple jar files on the host that match your pattern?

Comment: Hi Hans , it is a new azure agent every time and also i do cleanup before my docker build so for me it will have only one content_mgmt_service.jar file at a time , thanks

Comment: I suggest to `ls` the files in the jar directory before the `ADD` and check the content, what @HansKilian wrote sound right.
`RUN ls **/*`

Comment: I think may be a good catch , i ran couple of times but did not have the issue, some how for this service i did not clean the workspace and when i checked the failed history jobs the agents are same , so may be it would have had couple of jar at that time but unfortunately i did not have ls at the time , will monitor the future jobs , thanks guys